# Determine when I have crossed state line?

Tags: polygon, coordinates, google-maps-api

We are currently using the Google Maps API to get route information and total mileage but we would like to determine when we are crossing into a new state. When we return the route information we can be handed 2000+ Latitude and Longitude points. Initial thought was to do a lookup on each point to determine what state it was in but that would be very intensive. Another option would be to try and find a way to determine if the Lat & Long where inside a polygon or KMZ. Has anyone seen code for this?

Otherwise what other options should I be investigating?

Answer (score 1):

If you get the extents (bounding box) for each polygon, you can check points against those in code and only do polygon lookup for points that fall into 2 or more state bounding boxes.

For point-in-polygon testing, if you want to implement that in code, cast a ray from the point in an arbitrary direction (along x or y axis is best) and count the number of polygon edges (of all rings and holes) that it intersects.  Odd count is in the polygon, even count is not.

If you cast the ray along the X axis, (i.e. X increasing and invariant Y) than you can eliminate all edges where both endpoint X are less than point X or both endpoint Y are greater or less than point Y.  Where both segment Xs are greater and segment Ys are both above and below, count the segment.  You only need a true ray-segment intersection where segment Xs and Ys both fall on both sides of point X, Y.

Comment: Even that last check wouldn't need to be a full intersect test.  Just get the slope of the segment, then solve for X at the Y of the test point.  Count the segment if that X >= point X.

Comment: @Rod, are you even looking at the answers?  Do you need further assistance with the math?

Comment: I've already seen an implementation of that "ray casting method" in python. It's [here](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/01/point-in-polygon.html) and [here](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/08/point-in-polygon-2-on-line.html) for a version witch include the edge and vertex points.